# Is it necessary to use the ApplicationTest class in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is it necessary  to use the **ApplicationTest class** in newer version of android studio?
(Because when I created a new project, the class was not in the older version of android studio.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have this class in your project to run the app.
This class is used to test the application in a controlled environment.

It may not be possible to test the application on every type of device.
In that case, you can create customised environments to mimic the device on which you want to test your app.
You can create tests for different device configurations, databases, and Activity lifecycle events.

It extends the `ApplicationTestCase` class, calls its constructor and pass it Application.class as argument.

The `ApplicationTestCase` class in turn extends the `AndroidTestCase` class.

```
  android.test.AndroidTestCase
     ↳android.test.ApplicationTestCase<T extends android.app.Application>
          ↳class ApplicationTest
```

If you call `createApplication()` in your test, the test case will automatically call the `onCreate()` method to start the application so that it can run in the controlled environment. 
Similarly , the `tearDown()` method is automatically called at the end of the test. It in turn calls the `onDestroy()` method to destroy the application.

Answer (score -1):

We can know customers using location in an Android app can be tremendously useful. Users can take their devices all over the place and are continuously using them.  As developers can take advantage on that by providing a more related experience based on their existing position.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: please upload the meaning full information that relates to the question.